# Laravel - create folder with user->id on user registration

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems, directory, storage

I find function for user registeration:

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }

        Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));
    File::makeDirectory('/images/'.Auth::user()->id);

        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

but is possible to create folder inisde image folder with name $user->id so to create folder like /images/1

I try with

```
$result = File::makeDirectory('/images/'.Auth::user()->id);
```

but without success

I also try :

```
$directory = public_path().'\images'.Auth::user()->id;
File::makeDirectory($directory);
```

but again I just dont see folder ...

Is there any way to create folder inside public/images/user->id on user register

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set recursive to true as a third argument try this:

`File::makeDirectory(public_path().'/images/'.Auth::user()->id, 0755, true);`

Comment: Have you any idea what if user not logged in and i want to create user_id directory which is created??

Comment: can you explain more what do you want exactly to achieve

Comment: I've done it! Thanks for your reply. I just want to create directory when user register with their id and when user register he's not logged in so auth id not valid! But now get it with user->id when register. thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use the File facade within laravel, you could do the following:

```
use File;
File::makeDirectory(base_path("/images/".Auth::user()->id), 0755, $recursive = true, $force = false);
```

or:

```
use File;
File::makeDirectory(base_path("/images/".Auth::user()->id), 0755, true);
```